# Eclipse RCP Product for AIX ppc64 using Maven and Tycho

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-indigo, tycho

We are successfully building Eclipse Indigo(3.7) based RCP product for windows and Linux gtk 32 and 64 bit platforms, now we need to create products for AIX ppc64 bit as well, for that we have done following changes:

In pom.xml we added environment

```
<environment>
  <os>aix</os>
  <ws>gtk</ws>
  <arch>ppc</arch>
</environment>
<environment>
 <os>aix</os>
 <ws>gtk</ws>
 <arch>ppc64</arch>
</environment>
```

And in feature.xml we added following plugins

```
<plugin
         id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.aix.ppc"
         os="aix"
         ws="gtk"
         arch="ppc"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         fragment="true"
         unpack="false"/>
   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.aix.ppc64"
         os="aix"
         ws="gtk"
         arch="ppc64"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         fragment="true"
         unpack="false"/>
```

And

```
<plugin
         id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.aix.ppc"
         os="aix"
         arch="ppc"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         fragment="true"
         unpack="false"/>
   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.aix.ppc64"
         os="aix"
         arch="ppc64"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         fragment="true"
         unpack="false"/>
```

whenever we are executing pom using maven we are getting below error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.: [Unable to satisfy dependency from com.client.gui.feature.feature.group 6.0.0.qualifier to org.eclipse.core.filesystem.aix.ppc64 0.0.0.; No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.
```

Maven is not able to resolve dependency for org.eclipse.core.filesystem.aix.ppc64 plugin and only works for org.eclipse.core.filesystem.aix.ppc, Please let me know if the plugin org.eclipse.core.filesystem.aix.ppc64 is not part of eclipse 3.7 repository and external repository path needs to be added in pom.xml, Or am i missing any configuration apart from above mentioned one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've searched through the artifacts.xml index file for the Indigo release and whilst it has an entry for `org.eclipse.core.filesystem.aix.ppc`:

```
<artifact id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.aix.ppc" classifier="osgi.bundle" version="1.1.0.v20110423-0524">
  <processing size="1">
    <step id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.processing.Pack200Unpacker" required="true"/>
  </processing>
  <properties size="3">
  <property name="artifact.size" value="8770"/>
  <property name="download.size" value="7379"/>
  <property name="format" value="packed"/>
  </properties>
</artifact>
```

It doesn't have a corresponding entry for `org.eclipse.core.filesystem.aix.ppc64`. There is an entry for that bundle in the Kepler index so, unless you can get the bundle from elsewhere, it looks like your options are to not build the 64-bit release or move to a newer version of Eclipse.

Comment: just a thought, then how come delta pack is able to create build for aixppc64 if the plugin is not available in eclipse indigo repository?